# Showing dimensions at WooCommerce product meta variation product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I added - child/single-product/meta.php dimensions. If i have single product it works - [single product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3TAU.png) but if i have variation product is show nothing - [variation product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzT3i.png)

```
<?php
   $dimensions = $product->get_dimensions();
   if ( ! empty( $dimensions ) ) {
      echo '<div class="dimensions">Rozměry: š.' . $product->get_width();
      echo ' h.' . $product->get_length();
      echo ' v.' . $product->get_height() . " " . get_option( 'woocommerce_dimension_unit' );
      echo '</div>';        
   }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope his help you.

```
global $product;

$variations = $product->get_available_variations();
foreach ( $variations as $variable_array ){
    echo "<br>The length is. ".$variable_array['dimensions']['length'];
}
```

Comment: Giving me error: Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Invalid product.

Comment: Are you using single  product template?